# Xcode Unable to install "Runner" Code: -402620392 (Flutter app)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

XCode Version 11.1 (11A1027)
Flutter version 1.17.5

I try to run my Flutter App on IPad (12.4.6). It builds without errors, but on installing step shows the message

```
Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620392
Recovery Suggestion: The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.
--
The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620392
Failure Reason: Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018).
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a648047 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a648749 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a687824 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 158
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010fd3d756 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012a6875c1 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012a521f6c __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010fe6e9ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010fe70092 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e35e5f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e35f63d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e3658e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e366396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6e36e6ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e59f611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e59f3fd start_wqthread + 13
);
}
--
```

I tried to run this under my personal developer license (not paid acc) and under my company license (paid acc). All sertificates are valid 100%.
I recreated them all at some point but still no luck :(

Also was done:

1. `Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/` were cleared
2. `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` was cleared
3. Bundle Id - I`ve tried to change it
4. Tried to create new project and run it - successfully runs, but only first time, when it has almost no code inside. When I add some extra code and run `pod install` - it fails.

and the strange thing is that I have another Flutter project with no extra dependencies and I can delivery it to the same device.

Could it be that some packages or Info.plist settings like `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` ruin everything?

Can't find any interconnection...

Answer (score 2):

For everyone with the same issue, i tried for so long to fix that with all the others comments around the internet, but the mistake was more simple than looks like.
My pods_runner was in Embed & Sign, but it have to be by default on "Do not embed".

You can change it in : Runner > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embeded Content > Pods_Runner.framework.

Maybe is not a solution for everyone, but it was the one for me, good luck (:

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this problem for about a week, and finally just tried everything i could think of... What ended up working for me, was deleting the "code signing entitlements" that was generated for the project, because i notices that my other projects didn't have them.

**Go to the runner in Targets -> Build Settings -> Scroll down to "Code Signing Entitlements"** and delete them by pressing backspace on the keyboard!

After you have deleted them, it should look something like this image.

[Image of my Code Signing Entitlements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LatFM.png)

Let me know if this worked for anyone else :)

Comment: Hi Jacob!
Thank you for your comment!
Unfortunately this doesn`t work for me.
All fields in Code Signing Entitlements are clear but still no luck with installing an application to real device(