# Cannot run flutter project after add any package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

if I create a new flutter project and run the app on the physical device, I find no problem and it works normally
But when I add the package on the pubspec.yaml file
It does not work after it and remains the same problem and message

Error Message
Details

```
Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620392
Recovery Suggestion: The certificate used to sign "Runner" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.
--
The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620392
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008018)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
  0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012ca15c8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
  1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012ca54241 90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
  2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ee9d64b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
  3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012ca53f82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
  4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000012c8c4a10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
  5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010efcc17e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK + 7
  6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010efcdda0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
  7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6c7d353d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6c7d4727 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
  9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6c7da55e _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
  10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6c7db02b _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
  11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6c7e4bab _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
  12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ca644f2 _pthread_wqthread + 314
  13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ca634c3 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0 (Build 20A5343j)
Xcode 12.3 (17715) (Build 12C33)
Timestamp: 2021-01-25T01:27:20-08:00
```

Comment: Just in case you haven't see it already, something to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319993/xcode-unable-to-install-runner-code-402620392-flutter-app

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, this doesn`t work.
because my project is run but after add any package, It does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after update code_signing_required = NO in the SDKSettings.plist file,
get me this problem
I solved this problem by re-correct value to YES

Comment: can you please tell where to find this file in xcode?

Comment: @AyeshaIftikhar in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk

Comment: thanks but i have fixed the error, turns out we need to manage provisioning profile automatically instead of importing it manual to run a project on real iphone